# Complete CMS (or framework for CMS) with i18n support

Tags: django, google-app-engine, content-management-system, internationalization, joomla

We are looking for a way to publish articles in different languages, including differences in writing direction (*RTL/LTR*) and of course character sets. The maintainer of the current site works with Mambo/Joomla, but has already found severe restrictions in terms of extensibility.

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749758) has already been asked, but I will add feature and system requirements.

Feature-wise, we need the following functionality:

- CMS standard features (two-stage publishing, permissions, different publishing mechanisms …)
- In addition to standard categorization, articles should have a **language meta attribute**
- It should be possible to provide a **single article in one or more languages**

  - Links between articles should indicate the language of the target article, if it does not match the language of the source article.
  - It should be possible to link directly to an article published in a certain language (e.g. `mysite.com/article/23423/my-cool-title?lang=ar`).
- Authors should have some kind of indication of their language capabilities

At the level of system requirements, we have thought of the following alternatives:

- Standard PHP/MySQL on Apache (LAMP)
- Google App Engine (preferred django)

We are looking for a complete CMS, that can easily be extended and administrated, or a framework that covers most of the functionality. Please consider that we have already read through the answers on the [previously mentioned question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749758).

Thank you,

Kariem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drupal could very easily meet your needs on the LAMP stack. As of Drupal 6 almost everything you need is available. You can have:

- Multi stage publishing and workflow with the contributed Workflow module
- New content can be tagged in a specific language, or created as language neutral
- I don't know if it would be possible to have the CMS automatically list the target language of a link, but it shouldn't be hard with a few lines of code to add a filter something like [link: article ID or name] to insert a link to the other article that would list the language of the link target
- linking to a specific language/translation of an article is no problem, most folks set that up with path prefixing in Drupal, so an english article would be at example.com/en/article/path and say french at example.com/fr/article/path

Comment: Great answer, thank you! I had Drupal on my list, but did not want to invest too much time, but with this good answer I will have to take a look.

Comment: I just had time to take a more detailed look and installed Drupal 6 on a test machine. Everything is available, so I marked your reply as accepted answer. Some things are not directly available, but after installing some plugins all requirements can be met. Perhaps you could elaborate a little bit more about the needed plugins and add some pointers for others to follow. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at [Django-CMS](http://django-cms.org/) ?

I don't think it will have everything you mention out of the box, but most of it is there and the rest you can add yourself.

Comment: Yes, I already looked at Django CMS. The problem is that I am not sure, if it is possible to deploy it on App Engine (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478760/any-cms-is-google-app-engine-compatible/1023468#1023468).

Answer (score 1):

I used [Sitellite CMS](http://www.sitellite.org), it's a good software with I18n support.

Comment: I did not know Sitellite CMS yet, but I will have a look at it to see, whether I can really do what I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of anything that meets your requirements currently available on App Engine. You could customize something like [Bloog](http://bloog.billkatz.com/), though.

Comment: Thank you for the first answer to this question. I think it would be too much work to customize a blog software to fit the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [django-blocks](http://code.google.com/p/django-blocks/). Has multi-language Menu, Flatpages and even has a simple Shopping Cart!!