# Django localized templates

Tags: localization, internationalization, django-templates

How can create multilingual Django site?
Is it a good idea to create template set for each language?
How should I use that sets of templates (if it's a good idea)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this question: [How to localize Content of a Django application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366838/how-to-localize-content-of-a-django-application)

I'd say try to maintain the same template for each language. However, if you must, or if you feel it is reasonable, you can certainly use a set of different templates for certain other languages. For instance, I know that Arabic is read from right to left, so perhaps a different template is worthwhile in that case.